# Fetching WordPress page contents with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch

I would like to fetch all contents from a specific WordPress page but cannot manage to understand how to make it work. I am fetching the link to the WP page (https://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/pages) with a "GET" request in JS, which is working so far. However, I am not sure how to display the contents of the page (accessible by; **content.rendered** in the JSON I believe).

The only way I have every displayed content on the web page is by populating an HTML template, but it seems to not be working (maybe the wrong approach in this case?), since I only want the WP content to appear on my site.

```
function fetchHome() {
  let response = fetch(
    "https://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/146",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: getHome(),
    }
  );
}

function getHome() {
  const homepageTemplate = 
  document.querySelector("#homepageTemplate").content;
  const homepageTemplateCopy = homepageTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  const homepageContainer = document.querySelector("#homepage");

  homepageTemplateCopy.querySelector("h2.title").textContent =
    "Title: " + `${title.rendered}`;
  homepageTemplateCopy.querySelector(
    "p.paragraph"
  ).textContent = `${content.rendered}`;
  homepageContainer.appendChild(homepageTemplateCopy);
}
```

When replacing the .textContent within the template through object notation, I get an error saying that "title" or "content" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET request does not have a body, so it should be something like this:

```js
function fetchHome() {
  // Notice that we are now returning the result from the fetch function
  // and we no longer have the body property.
  return fetch(
    "https://mauriciolondono.be/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/146", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      }
    }
  );
}

function getHome(response) {
  const homepageTemplate = document.querySelector("#homepageTemplate");
  const homepageTemplateCopy = homepageTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  const homepageContainer = document.querySelector("#homepage");

  homepageTemplateCopy.querySelector("h2.title").innerHTML = "Title: " + `${response.title.rendered}`;
  homepageTemplateCopy.querySelector("p.paragraph").innerHTML = `${response.content.rendered}`;
  homepageContainer.appendChild(homepageTemplateCopy);
}

fetchHome()
  .then(response => response.json()) // Converts the HTTP request stream into a JSON object
  .then(response => getHome(response)); // You will need to adjust the getHome function accordingly, but now that function receives the request response as a JSON object.
```

```html
<div id="homepageTemplate">
  <h2 class="title"></h2>
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
</div>

<div id="homepage">
  <h2 class="title"></h2>
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
</div>
```

The `fetchHome` function now returns a `promise`, so you will have to attach your callback to it. More on promises can be found on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I did my best to infer the HTML from your JS but sharing your HTML would be helpful.

As a side note, be careful when injecting content directly into your code, like we are doing with the `innerHTML` property, if malicious code is present on the JSON response and you attach it to the DOM, you can get an undesired result. So you either trust the content provider or if you cannot, you need to serialize your data before injecting into the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the part I am struggling with is how to build the getHome() function so that it fetches the content I need from that specific WP page. Right now, it is successfully fetching with the "GET" request I have created.

Comment: I improved my answer. Let me know if this is what you needed.